# How can I return function arguments args, kwargs in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to have a function the user specifies to return function arguments to another function.

```
def wrapper(func, arg_func, iters=10):
    for i in range(iters):
        args, kwargs = arg_func()
        f(*args, **kwargs)
```

is this possible? Currently if I return a tuple from `arg_func` without any `kwargs` then it complains about too many arguments to unpack.

```
wrapper(func=print, arg_func=lambda: (random.uniform(0.0, 1.0),))

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Comment: but the lambda only returns the result of calling `uniform`, you don't return anything else from it so there's only one argument that can be unpacked.

Comment: Exactly, I guess the lambs is just an example but I'm unsure of how to return arbitrary arguments in form args kwargs regardless

Comment: Well you need a function that actually returns them (a list and a dictionary), supplying a function that doesn't will lead to wrong behavior.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want to do with this, but if the function you provide into arg_func has a return statement that returns two variables (a list and a dictionary), then those values will be stored into args and kwargs in respective order.

Comment: @Neelik I understand that. I am trying to account for the situation where the user provides a `func` which takes positional and keyword arguments. To generate arguments for `func` with `arg_func` they would need to return a tuple and a dictionary. But, similar to how keyword options are often optional to function calls, I would like to not force them to return a `dict` from `arg_func` if they do not have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `arg_func` needs to return a sequence of two elements, the first of which is a sequence itself and the second is a dictionary.

Here is one way to invoke `wrapper()`. Note that the first element of the return value is a tuple `(random.uniform(0.0, 1.0),)` and the second is a dictionary `{'flush':True}`. These values are simply examples. use whatever sequence and dictionary are appropriate for your code.

```
wrapper(func=print,
        arg_func=lambda: ((random.uniform(0.0, 1.0),), {'flush':True}))
```

Here is a another example. `arg_func` returns two positional arguments and no keyword arguments:

```
wrapper(func=print, arg_func=lambda: (("Hello","World"), {}))
```

Comment: Do I have to add the extra flush kwarg?

Comment: you do need to add an extra mapping object (empty or not) or else you'll get bitten by the `**kwargs` after that.

Comment: No, you don't need `'flush'`. I only used it for the sake of the example. If you have no key word arguments to pass, just use `{}` as the dict.

Comment: I understand that, I would rather not force the user to pass any dict though, if not necessary

Answer (score 0):

You can do some extra handling. Something like

```
args, *more_args = arg_func()
kwargs = more_args[0] if more_args else {}
```

(Also if you're not using 3.x you'll need to do something like

```
x = arg_func()
a,k = (x[0] if len(x) else []), (x[1] if len(x) > 1 else {})
```